# Как передать в функцию неопределенное количество переменных?

Tags: php

Как передать в функцию неопределенное количество однотипных переменных? Можно ли такое сделать?

> function ($array1, $aray2,....,
> $arrayN) { //тут пробежаться в цикле
> по ним }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)